# How to know that MERGE operation was INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let say I have,

```
MERGE INTO SHARE_AD_GROUP A
USING (
    SELECT SHARE_AD_GROUP_ID,
        SHARE_ID,
        AD_GROUP,
        SHARE_PERMISSIONS
    FROM SHARE_AD_GROUP
    WHERE SHARE_ID = @shareID AND AD_GROUP = @ownerId
) B ON (A.SHARE_AD_GROUP_ID = B.SHARE_AD_GROUP_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET A.SHARE_PERMISSIONS = B.SHARE_PERMISSIONS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SHARE_PERMISSIONS) VALUES(@sharePermissions);

-- In Here how do I know that it is insert or update
```

How to know that MERGE operation was INSERT or UPDATE after INSERT OR UPDATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c06e1db4-7fd6-43c4-8569-5335d555dac8/record-count-on-merge-statement-on-insertupdatedelete)

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));

MERGE tblTarget AS Target
USING (SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM tblSource) 
    AS Source
ON (Target.Col1 = Source.Col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.Col2 = source.Col2 -- Need to get affected rows here
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Col1,Col2) VALUES (Col1,Col2); -- Need to get affected rows here
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

SELECT Change, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange
FROM @SummaryOfChanges
GROUP BY Change;
```

Comment: Try this SQL. You should be able to see the change log of the operation