# Is there a way to know what operation was performed in MERGE?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Using jOOQ and PostgreSQL, is there a way to know what operation was executed for a MERGE, INSERT or UPDATE?

E.g. using the example from jOOQ's documentation:

```java
create.mergeInto(AUTHOR)
      .using(create.selectOne())
      // Suppose the last name is unique (natural key) in my case
      .on(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.eq("Hitchcock"))
      .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
      .set(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, "John")
      .whenNotMatchedThenInsert(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
      .values("Hitchcock")
      .execute();
```

Ideally, I'd get both the resulting row and what operation was executed, if possible.

**Note:** Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985050/how-to-know-that-merge-operation-was-insert-or-update). That one is SQL Server specific. Mine is PostgreSQL and jOOQ specific.

Comment: It returns how many rows are effected, right? If you want to know which fields are updated or similar thing, you need to keep history of that table.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I don't need to know what exactly was updated, just wether it was updated at all or newly inserted during the MERGE.

Comment: If you need it in Database, then you can use trigger. If it is needed in code, most probably you need to send a select query. Because database does not return that information when insert or update is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) can't use a `RETURNING` clause for its underlying `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, so you're just left with a total number of rows that were affected, without any indication of how they were affected. [Doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html#id-1.9.3.156.8)

> On successful completion, a `MERGE` command returns a command tag of the form
>
> `MERGE total_count`
>
> The `total_count` is the total number of rows changed (whether inserted, updated, or deleted).

> There is no `RETURNING` clause with `MERGE`. Actions of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` cannot contain `RETURNING` or `WITH` clauses.

You could use the older *upsert* syntax [`INSERT...ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) which is able to use a `RETURNING` clause, and in it, check [`xmax` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-XMAX) of affected rows: inserted ones will always have zero, the updated ones will have non-zero. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453960/5298879).

jOOQ offers both [`.onConflict()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-conflict/) and [`.returningResult()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-returning/) (just [`.returning()` before 3.11](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-returning/)). The problematic part seems to be the exposure of the hidden system column, that you might not be able to reference  straight away. If that's still the case, you'll need a [plain SQL `field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(java.lang.String))  (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58025553/5298879)).

In case it's too much trouble to reach `xmax` and you don't mind littering your schema, it's possible to set up [a reflector column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453513/5298879) instead of trying to use the hidden `xmax`. Or, if you're sure your insert batch never contains the conflict resolution values, count the ones that ended up using them.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```java
create.mergeInto(AUTHOR)
      .using(create.selectOne())
      // Suppose the last name is unique (natural key) in my case
      .on(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.eq("Hitchcock"))
      .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
      .set(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, "John")
      .set(AUTHOR.LAST_ACTION, "UPDATE")
      .whenNotMatchedThenInsert(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_ACTION)
      .values("Hitchcock", "INSERT")
      .execute();
```

And then read the record again, because PostgreSQL's `MERGE` doesn't support the standard SQL `<data change delta table>` syntax, or equivalent.

You can also automate the above in a trigger. Instead of storing the `LAST_ACTION` in the table, such a trigger could also use the [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) command to indicate to clients what it did, for each row.

Comment: In the two-step workaround, unless you wrap both operations in a transaction, you risk reading a `LAST_ACTION` that doesn't correspond to what you just `MERGED` but instead to something someone else did in between your `MERGE` and the subsequent `SELECT`. In the `INSERT...ON CONFLICT` equivalent of this I'm calling that additional column a reflector, because you can bounce the operation type info off it, on statement level, so there's no need for the additional operation.

Comment: The `trigger`+`table` or `trigger`+`notify` side-channel feedback require you to also identify statements so that clients can tell what's theirs from the broadcasted notifications (I doubt passing their desired `listen` channel to be picked up by the trigger to directly `notify` them on is viable). For that it would make sense for the client to save its transaction info, which could be correlated with system columns visible in the trigger (cmin/cmax/xmin/xmax that correspond to client's context).